# Retrieve hashed PHP password from database and check against a submitted password in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an options page in my project and in that I can change my password.
I have a form where it asks you to enter **current password**, **new password** and **confirm password**.
I check all data for errors and send this to the server using **jQuery ajax**.

The only problem I have is that I need to check my **current password** against the password stored in the database.

The database password is hashed using PHP **SHA1($database_password.$salt);**

I was thinking that I pass the PHP variables, **$database_password** and **$salt** to Javascript somehow and then use **sha1()** js alternative [sha1 javascript code](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html) to see if my **current password** matches the **database password**.

Can anyone give me any pointers or is there alternative ways?

Comment: Why do you want to test this on the client? Moreover, why do you ask for the current password at all, if a user is logged in?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Requesting the current password is a security precaution. If you are logged in and walk away from your computer, someone else can't change your password without knowing the current password.

Comment: @Arjan: yeah, I know, but walking away is a risk anyway: someone can send mails on your behalf, interact with the system, etc. Anyway, I'd say: just don't check this on the client, merely check the conformity and complexity of the new password and leave the comparison to the server, that will save you a lot hassle and in normal cases hardly degrade user experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to leave the password hash on the server. You can do an ajax request with the current password and have the server validate it. That way the hash remains unknown to the user and a brute force attack is more difficult.

Of course you only should send the current password (and the new password) once the user indicates that he has finished typing (ie. when he clicks the submit button).

Comment: +1 for letting the hash on the server to make brute-force attacks more difficult. In case you only send the passwords when clicking the submit button, you don't have to do an Ajax request, you can just (let the browser) post the form.